# Usage of if constexpr in template

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, if-constexpr

I am trying to understand the utility of if constexpr and want to know if there is any utility in using it in this way.

```
template<bool B>
int fun()
{
    if constexpr (B)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Is this function changed at all by using if constexpr instead of a regular if? I assume the performance would be the same. My understanding of templates is that the outcome of the if statement is already known at compile time so there is no difference.

Comment: The utility of if constexpr lies in the fact that the statements in the branch that is not taken are *not instantiated*, so one could use if constexpr where a regular if would yield a type error.

Comment: From experience I noticed that `if constexpr` is only really useful with proper `else` or another `else if constexpr`. Otherwise the fallback instruction is always instantiated which is normally not wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utility of `constexpr`?

A trivial example... if you write the following function

```
template <typename T>
auto foo (T const & val)
{
   if ( true == std::is_same_v<T, std::string>> )
      return val.size()
   else
      return val;
}
```

and call it with an integer

```
foo(42);
```

you get a compilation error, because the instruction

```
val.size();
```

has to be instantiated also when `val` is an `int` but, unfortunately, `int` isn't a class with a `size()` method

But if you add `constexpr` after the `if`

```
// VVVVVVVVV
if constexpr ( true == std::is_same_v<T, std::string>> )
   return val.size()
```

now the `return val.size();` instruction is instantiated *only* when `T` is `std::string`, so you can call `foo()` also with arguments without a `size()` method.

---- EDIT ----

As @prapin observed in a comment (thanks!), `if constexpr` can be necessary for an `auto` function.

I propose another trivial (and silly) example

Without `if constexpr`, the following `bar()` function

```
template <typename T>
auto bar (T const &)
{
   if ( true == std::is_same_v<T, std::string>> )
      return 42;
   else
      return 42L;
}
```

doesn't compile, because the first `return` return a `int` value, the second return a `long`; so, given that without `if constexpr` the compiler must instantiate both `return`'s, so the compiler can't conciliate the `return`s types and can't determine the return type of the function.

With `if constexpr`,

```
   if constexpr ( true == std::is_same_v<T, std::string>> )
      return 42;
   else
      return 42L;
```

the compiler instantiate the first `return` **or** the second one; never both. So the compiler ever determine the type returned from the function (`int` when called with a `std::string`, `long` otherwise).

Comment: Also, as your example in fact suggests with the `auto` return type, with `if constexp` each branch is allowed to return a *different* type, which is not possible with a normal `if`.

Comment: @prapin - Good point. Simple to explain and useful. Added in my answer. Thanks!